# Storybook's story files written in TypeScript is not handled properly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, storybook

I recently migrated my CRA project to Next.js
I was using Storybook in that project, so had to edit lots of configurations, but there are still TypeScript related problems remaining.

This is the example of my story file.

```
import { ComponentStory, ComponentMeta } from '@storybook/react';

import Index from 'pages/profile';

export default {
  title: 'Views/Profile',
  component: Index,
} as ComponentMeta<typeof Index>;

export const IndexTemplate: ComponentStory<typeof Index> = (args) => <Index {...args} />;
```

Whenever I run storybook, 'as' got an error like this:

```
 at Parser._raise (/Users/hannah/work/pomelo-micro/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:150:45)
    at Parser.raiseWithData (/Users/hannah/work/pomelo-micro/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:145:17)
    at Parser.raise (/Users/hannah/work/pomelo-micro/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:89:17)
    at Parser.semicolon (/Users/hannah/work/pomelo-micro/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/util.js:143:10)
    at Parser.parseExportDefaultExpression (/Users/hannah/work/pomelo-micro/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:2118:10)
    at Parser.parseExport (/Users/hannah/work/pomelo-micro/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:1993:31)
    at Parser.parseStatementContent (/Users/hannah/work/pomelo-micro/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:431:25)
    at Parser.parseStatement (/Users/hannah/work/pomelo-micro/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:329:17)
    at Parser.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (/Users/hannah/work/pomelo-micro/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:1073:25)
    at Parser.parseBlockBody (/Users/hannah/work/pomelo-micro/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:1049:10)
    at Parser.parseProgram (/Users/hannah/work/pomelo-micro/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:214:10)
    at Parser.parseTopLevel (/Users/hannah/work/pomelo-micro/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:197:25)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/hannah/work/pomelo-micro/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/index.js:41:10)
    at parse (/Users/hannah/work/pomelo-micro/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/index.js:58:38)
    at parser (/Users/hannah/work/pomelo-micro/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/parser/index.js:52:34)
    at parser.next (<anonymous>)
    at processResult (/Users/hannah/work/pomelo-micro/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:753:19)
    at /Users/hannah/work/pomelo-micro/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:855:5
    at /Users/hannah/work/pomelo-micro/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:399:11
    at /Users/hannah/work/pomelo-micro/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:251:18
    at context.callback (/Users/hannah/work/pomelo-micro/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:124:13)
    at /Users/hannah/work/pomelo-micro/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:59:103
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /Users/hannah/work/pomelo-micro/src/stories/views/profile/Update.stories.tsx: Missing semicolon. (23:1)
```

and this is .storybook/main.ts file I have. I installed `@storybook/preset-typescript` addon as it seemed to solve this problem.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  typescript: {
    check: false,
    checkOptions: {},
    reactDocgen: 'react-docgen-typescript',
    reactDocgenTypescriptOptions: {
      compilerOptions: {
        allowSyntheticDefaultImports: false,
        esModuleInterop: false,
      },
      shouldExtractLiteralValuesFromEnum: true,
      propFilter: (prop) => (prop.parent ? !/node_modules/.test(prop.parent.fileName) : true),
    },
  },
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    config.resolve.alias = {
      ...config.resolve.alias,
      // mock module for storybook testing
      'next/image': path.resolve(__dirname, '../__mocks__/next/image.js'),
      'next/link': path.resolve(__dirname, '../__mocks__/next/link.js'),
      'next/router': path.resolve(__dirname, '../__mocks__/next/router.js'),
    };

    return config;
  },
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@storybook/preset-create-react-app',
    '@storybook/addon-queryparams',
    'storybook-react-i18next',
    '@storybook/preset-typescript',
  ],

  framework: '@storybook/react',
  core: {
    builder: 'webpack5',
  },
};
```

I had to add webpack5 builder as it's documented on Storybook's official page to convert the project to Next.js. I am not sure what exactly causing this issue yet.

[Error log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NBMR.png)

Comment: did you manage to resolve this? I think I might have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

It might just be now that you have an error:

`SyntaxError: /Users/hannah/work/pomelo-micro/src/stories/views/profile/Update.stories.tsx: Missing semicolon. (23:1)`

Check the file and add a semi-colon?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought so in the beginning too. but the code itself has all semi-colon at the end of its line. That's why I thought Storybook is handling TypeScript in a weird way.